# PHPUnit 5.3 prepare data in multiple schemas

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, php-5.5

My code that I want to test is collecting data from different tables in different DB schemas. How Can I test it using PHPUnit? How can I prepare XML dataset file to populate different schemas with required data?

Thanks in advance.